# Does Disabling Page Level Locking Have an Adverse Effect on Other DBs

Tags: sql-server-2012, locking

I got the following from a vendor about what their software (“IM”) needs:

“IM needs its own SQL Server Instance if the DB is installed on a shared SQL server. This is a mandatory prerequisite because IM handles a lot things differently than a typical MS SQL standard database. These differences will normally slow down other databases (for example IM switches the SQL server from page level locking mode to row level locking mode which is faster for IM but slower for a lot of other databases - this is because of the asynchronous architecture).”

Admittedly, I don’t know a lot about the benefits of one locking type over another but I thought page and row level locking were handled inside a database.  Why would disabling page level locking have an adverse effect on other DBs in a shared instance?  Or would it?

Comment: Changes to a single database's I/O patterns and memory needs can certainly impact anything else on the box. Just like one car stopped in a travel lane can cause disastrous results to all of the lanes on the highway.